# get_or_create gives IntegrityError: Duplicate entry for key 'PRIMARY'"

Tags: mysql, django

This has been driving me crazy, I have the following code:

```
category, created = Category.objects.get_or_create(name=category_name, user=self.user)
```

that raises `django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry '566' for key 'PRIMARY'")`

I read on other similar issues on stackoverflow that I need to add `defaults` in my get_or_create, but the thing is that all my other params apart from the two that I specify have default values. Also, replacing the code above by:

```
try:
    test = Category.objects.get(name=category_name, user=self.user)
except Category.DoesNotExist:
    test = Category(name=category_name, user=self.user)
    test.save()
```

Works.

Model definition:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    objects = ModelManager()

    name = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True
    )
    description = models.TextField(default="")
    hashed_id = models.CharField(max_length=16, default="")
    is_shared = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

What in hell is happening?
For info, I am using mysql

UPDATE: It also turns out that the key that is signaled as duplicate **DOES NOT** exist before the creation of the new instance. The `get_or_create` creates a new instance with a key that is not used and then somehow find the key it just created and throw a `Duplicate entry` error...

Comment: can u update question with model definition?

Comment: mention models first.

Comment: use defaults={'description': "", 'hashed_id': "", ''is_shared': FALSE} see what happens?

Comment: @Sagar You mean having the fields before setting the value of objects? `name = models.CharField(max_length=70) ... objects = ModelManager()` ? I tried and it doesn't change anything

Comment: @Sagar, if I add the defaults as you said it works but the whole point of setting default values is that I don't want to specify them each time. This means that every time I add a new field, I will have to search my get_or_creates and update them -_-

Comment: Hm you are right but I was just checking if it works by adding default or any other problem occuring?

Comment: No, as far as I know that's the only one. What is even weirder is that it used to work fine for months. I think it broke when I upgraded from django 1.10 to 1.11 but I wouldn't be able to say precisely. It may have broke silently earlier without me noticing.

Comment: is that self.request.user of self.user

Comment: It's self.user. I am inside the function of another model which creates the category with based on its own user.

Comment: I wish this question had answers... .